# Django 1.11 Json Models

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a Django Models Database with an object with entries as such for a checklist inside a report.

JSON File:

```
{
    'int id':{
        'description': string,
        'value': bool, # yes/no ... represented by true/false
        'remarks': string
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

such that when I import:

```
data = filename.json
list ={}
with open('data', 'r') as read_file:
    raw_data = json.load(read_file)

i = 0
if i < len(raw_data): # Make sure we don't go out of bounds
    # Cycle thru data
    for id in raw_data:
        s = str(i)
        list[i] = {}
        list[i]['Description'] = raw_data[s]["Description"]
        list[i]['Value'] = raw_data[s]["Value"]
        list[i]['Remarks'] = raw_data[s]["Remarks"]
        i = i+1

...
...
...

class Report (models.Model):

    ...
    ... Other items like reporter's name, etc
    ...
    checklist = list{}
```

I want to populate this model as such. And I can edit them under the Reports model in the admin page. However i cannot fins what method to use to properly do this. I have tried choice but it’s not what i want.

Edit:
Essentially I want to be able to create those areas for Django Administration to be a part of a

`class foo (model.Models):`

Example:
[image: example]

For a better resolution:
https://ibb.co/MZcJ2jB

Such that I will have a website where non-admin users can submit reports and be able to make changes to their selection if needed.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code.

```
data = {"description": "",
        "name": "",
        "last_name": ""}

model = ""
model += "class Person(models.Model):\n"

for key, value in data.iteritems():
    entity = "    {} = models.CharField(max_length=30)\n".format(key)
    model += entity

model += "\n"
model += "def __str__(self): \n"
model += "    return self.name"

print(model)
```

it will return this.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self): 
    return self.name
```

after this simply save a .py with the following string as a file.
hope it helps.

Comment: I tried implementing your code however, I did not see any changes to my model.

Comment: @jye0325 did you execute commands python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate after saving the created file so it can take the changes into the database schema?

Comment: So I've tried saving it as a separate .py file. Ran makemigrations and then migrate. nothing changed. Ive also tried importing it as well. 

I updated the issue on the op. Is that what your solution would help output for me?

Comment: @jye0325 please add an object to your model and then execute python manage.py dumpdata > mymodel.json this will export your model data edit that with the data you want and then to uploadit again do it on an empty model or remove pk from the JSON file and execute python manage.py loaddata mymodel.json I think this is what you mean??

Comment: Yeah I still couldn't get your solution to work. I decided to change the database to Djongo and use embedded models instead, which solved that issue.